# Fragment navigation does not work with back button on ActionBar, ok with physical

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

With Android target API 24, minver 15, I am writing an app based on the "*One Activity, Multiple Fragments*" philosophy and I can't go "up" the hierarchy of Fragments via the **back button on the ActionBar**.

*No problems with the **physical one** on the phone.*

I am highliting it because even though I found many similar questions and tutorials, in this case the problem *does not seem to be Navigation per se*, as the only thing not working is the back caret press.

This is the current Fragment hierarchy:

```
[A] [B]
 |
[C]
```

Everything works as expected when I go, from the NavigationDrawer, to `Fragments [A]` and `[B]`. Inside `Fragment [A]`, which contains a `ListView`, I then click on an element that brings me to `Fragment [C]` with the following code:

### FragmentA.java

```
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame, new DetailFragment())
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

This way, `Fragment [C]` gets shown and the hamburger icon becomes the back caret. I can navigate to the previous `Fragment [A]` clicking on the physical back button on the Android phone (the bottom one), but clicking on the back caret does nothing.

The relevant code, with comment on (missed) execution, for the other parts follows.

### MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
/* ... */
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        /* IF I CLICK ON THE "SETTINGS" BUTTON
        *  IN THE ActionBar, THIS GETS EXECUTED 
        *  BUT IS NEVER EXECUTED ON "BACK CARET" PRESS
        */
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Activity onOptionsItemSelected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    /* THIS GETS EXECUTED WHEN I PRESS THE PHYSICAL 
    *  BACK BUTTON ON THE PHONE
    */
    Toast.makeText(this, "BACK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

### FragmentC.java

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    /* NEVER EXECUTED.*/
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fragment onOptionsItemSelected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I've read various Android Docs and questions/answers here on SO and implemented more or less everything stated, but with no success.

**How to make the ActionBar back button work?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I (well, the example NavigationDrawer Android project) was using the Toolbar.

In this case, for back to work you need to add something like:

```
    mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    );
```

All the usual methods won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
   ((MainActivity)getActivity()).mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.frame, new DetailFragment())//here add add fragment on stack 
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

Comment: Does not work and, worse, `Fragment [A]` and `Fragment [C]` are shown overlayed. Pressing the physical back button removes the `Fragment [C]` overlay, but the ActionBar's back does nothing anyway.